# Added Transparency to Wrapper Background.But on Contents it shows it too

Tags: html, css

I have to make a white transparent background only. But it is showing contents transparent also. Is there any way that only Background should be transparent, not the Contents on it.
Please Help me to solve it.

My CSS Codes are

```
html{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
body{
width:99%;
min-width:300px;
max-width:500px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:#04AFFF;
}
#wrapper{
width:98%;
max-width:490px;
min-height:300px;
margin:0 auto;
padding-top:125px;
background-image: url("guy.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center top;
border:1px dotted red;
background-size:100% auto;
}
.contents{
width:90%;
max-width:480px;
min-height:400px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:white;
border-radius:15px;
padding:10px;
opacity: 0.7;
filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.field{
width:90%;
height:40px;
color:black;
border:2px solid #2DC2F9;
border-radius:10px;
margin-left:4%;
margin-right:4%;
margin-top:10px;
background-color:white !important;
}
```

HTML is Here

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="contents">
        <form name="login" method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" Placeholder="Phone" required class="field"><br />
            <input type="text" Placeholder="Phone" required class="field">
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the color in `rgb` and use the `rgba` attribute to set opacity also:

```
.contents{
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) /* 0.7 is opacity */
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/gqxvg391/

Note: `rgb(255, 255, 255)` is equivalent to `white`. Learn more about CSS colors [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp).